# Meshlab: How to mapping a PLY mesh to planar image?

Tags: c#, kinect, meshlab, ply-file-format

im new in image processsing and 3D applications.
I have a PLY mesh from Kinect. I want to mapping the whole model to a planar image.

I imagine the result image like a tissue, flaterned in a planar surface from a topograifc surface.

My worry is dont lose the color depth image data or mesures from the original mesh.

Solutions in C# to mapping the mesh are welcome too.

Thanks!
( sorry my english)

Comment: What have you tried, so far?

Comment: Nothing, I cant find a satisfactory solution, yet

Comment: Do you want to unwrap the 3D mesh on a 2D surface? Or are you looking for something similar to texture atlas generation?

Comment: I think both of approches